# using preventDefault() with on() in jQuery AJAX tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, preventdefault

I have a set of jQuery UI AJAX tabs that load individual .php pages when they are clicked. All of my styling, etc. conveys, because the pages that hold the tabs widget provide the already linked CSS, and scripts. When it comes to the actual pages that load when clicking on the tabs however, I can't seen to get preventDefault() to work with .on() on these newly created DOM elements.

I'm using jQuery BBQ with my tabs so I can't have "#"s being appended to the URL. This is caused when links within the tab panels are clicked. 
I've been able to successfully use preventDefault() on DOM elements that are initially loaded, but not ones that are being fetched into the tabs widget via AJAX.

My function for a content toggler is...

```
$(function(){
$(".showMoreOrLess").on('click', (function() {
if (this.className.indexOf('clicked') != -1 ) {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).prev().slideUp(500);
    $(this).html("Read More" + "<span class='moreUiIcon'></span>");
    }
    else {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).prev().slideDown(500);
    $(this).html("See Less" + "<span class='lessUiIcon'></span>");
    }       
}));
});
```

I'd like to combine the preventDefault() from this function into it.

```
// prevents default link behavior on BBQ history stated tab panels with "showMoreOrLess" links
$(".showMoreOrLess").click(function (event) 
{ 
 event.preventDefault(); 
 //here you can also do all sort of things 
});
 // /prevents default behavior on "showMoreOrLess" links
```

I've tried several ways using .on("click", function(work)), etc. I've used .on() in a separate function and also tried to combine it in the first function above. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The code works on tab content that is static, just not content loaded via AJAX. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Can't seem to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("body").on('click', ".showMoreOrLess", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.hasClass('clicked')) {
    self.html("Read More" + "<span class='moreUiIcon'></span>").removeClass('clicked').prev().slideUp(500);
  }else {
    self.html("See Less" + "<span class='lessUiIcon'></span>").addClass('clicked').prev().slideDown(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Relic! Thank you so much! Not only did you solve the problem with preventDefault using .on(), but you graciously consolidated the code in the function with fewer inline uses of $(this). I really appreciate the help and your time. At first the code didn't work because I think I had remnants of the original function, but using yours alone works on both static and AJAX loaded UI tab panel content. You Rock!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of such help! `-Cheers`

Answer (score 1):

the part `$(".showMoreOrLess").click` just applies to already accessable links on your page

try to use event delegation (here the clicks are captured on an every time existing element and you just pass the selector it is watching for... as a nice side effect you save listeners

```
$(document).on("click", ".showMoreOrLess", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  //here you can also do all sort of things 
});
```

rather than document use a certain id from your page `$("#myContainerId")` (EDIT: of course the elements you are clicking on need to be inside of the element with the id)

Comment: Thanks so much. This works when using "body" as the selector. I've chosen to use Relic's suggestion below as the function has been consolidated with fewer uses of $(this) that I originally had. I tried to mark yours as the answer as well, but I guess SO only allows one per thread for me. I appreciate your time.

Comment: it is not about getting reputation but helping each other :)

Comment: You bet! Thanks for understanding.